# My GTX 1060 GPU doesn’t work on Blender 2.9 as OptiX

Tags: gpu

[image]

[image: gif]

I understand that the non RTX GPU has also been changed to use OptiX in this 2.9 update.

However, my GPU (GTX 1060) outputs a message when OptiX is selected that it will be rendered as a CPU and actually the rendering speed is slower than Cuda and the same as CPU. I rebooted the PC, but the result was still the same.

Am I misunderstanding this update?

Comment: The GTX 1060 should be supported (see [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Cycles#GPU_Rendering)). My guess would be that you're using an older graphics driver. Try to update it and check if detects the GPU as OptiX device. The driver can be downloaded from [Nvidia's website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/162983/en-us).

Comment: Yes, it was a driver problem. I installed the latest driver and now OptiX is working. It was faster than CUDA in rendering, but it was a very small time difference. And for viewport denoising, it was much faster than Intel AI denoising. Very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nvidia GTX 1060 is supported for rendering with OptiX (see [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Cycles#GPU_Rendering)), but it requires a current graphics driver. Updating it should allow you to select the GPU as OptiX render device for Cycles. The current drivers can be downloaded from [Nvidia's website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).